# Bootstrap dropdown submenu not showing based on parent id

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-5

I have a problem with make dropdown menu and submenu with bootstrap on Vue 3 and bootstrap 5.2

There is my json menu data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Menu 1",
        "active": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-11-20T03:27:47.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-20T03:27:47.000000Z",
        "sub_menus": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "menuId": 1,
                "name": "Sub Menu 1",
                "active": 1,
                "created_at": "2022-11-20T03:27:57.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-11-20T03:27:57.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "menuId": 1,
                "name": "Sub Menu 2",
                "active": 1,
                "created_at": "2022-11-20T06:31:59.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-11-20T06:31:59.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Menu 2",
        "active": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-11-20T12:02:16.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-20T12:02:16.000000Z",
        "sub_menus": []
    }
]
```

And its should be:

```
Menu 1
    Sub Menu 1
    Sub Menu 2
Menu 2
```

And then there is my html script:

```
            <div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" v-for="(menu, menuIndex) in menus" :key="menuIndex" role="button"
                id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ menu.name }}

                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" v-for="(item, index) in menu.sub_menus" :key="index">{{ item.name }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But the result is not what i expected, its showing like this:

```
Menu 1
    Sub Menu 1
    Sub Menu 2
Menu 2
    Sub Menu 1
    Sub Menu 2
```

And its not correctly. Maybe the problem is with my bootstrap class. Is there any suggestion for this problem? Thanks before for the help.

Comment: Is it working fine with only HTML?

Comment: yes its working with only HTML @IrshadKhan

Answer (score 0):

you have to try nested loop for it.

```
<div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" v-for="(menu, menuIndex) in menus" :key="menuIndex" role="button"
            :id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ menu.name }}
            
        <div v-if="menu.sub_menus">
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" v-for="(item, index) in menu.sub_menus"
            :key="index">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ item.name }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It still not work sir, still showing same result.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using id="dropdownMenuLink" for parent div and aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" for child div, please make sure them are dynamic with index

Comment: i have try to manual or dynamic rename for id and aria-labelledby to have the same name with menu parent name. But its still not working.

Comment: For example, id=menu-1 and aria-labelledby=menu-1 still not working

Comment: You should move v-for="(item, index) in menu.sub_menus" from <div> tag to <a> tag.
You can refer to: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: yes its better now, but the submenu still showing at all menu parent. While menu 2 doesnt have submenu

Comment: Your `sub_menus ` of the menu 2 is empty array, so menu 2 doesn't have submenu is correct, that right ?

Comment: yes i that what i mean. But menu 2 also showing submenu for menu 1, it should not like that

Comment: please try it end give me your feedback
```
<div v-for="(menu, menuIndex) in menus" :key="menuIndex" >
      <div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"role="button" :id="menuIndex" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ menu.name }}
        <div v-if="menu.sub_menus.length">
          <div class="dropdown-menu" :aria-labelledby="menuIndex" >
            <a v-for="(item, index) in menu.sub_menus" :key="index" class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ item.name }}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-for="(menu, menuIndex) in menus" :key="menuIndex" >
      <div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"role="button" :id="menuIndex" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ menu.name }}
        <div v-if="menu.sub_menus.length">
          <div class="dropdown-menu" :aria-labelledby="menuIndex" >
            <a v-for="(item, index) in menu.sub_menus" :key="index" class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ item.name }}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope it can help you